# Trying to install kivy for python on mac os 10.12

Tags: macos, kivy, python-3.4

so I am trying to install kivy on my mac.From their instructions page, I am on step 2, and have to enter the command `$ USE_OSX_FRAMEWORKS=0 pip install kivy`. However, when I put this in terminal, I get the error `error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1`, and as a result `Failed building wheel for kivy`. Does anyone know how to address this issue?

Comment: do you have xcode installed?

Comment: @Juggernaut yes i do, and i have also installed the tools associated with it

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue, and was able to fix it following the directions on the kivy mac OS X install page, with one modification as follows:

`$ brew install pkg-config sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer`

`$ pip3 install Cython==0.25.2`

`$ pip3 install kivy`

pip3 is my reference to pip for Python 3.6 as I have two different versions of python on my system. May just be `pip install` for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upon further research, seems like you can also do `pip install Cython==0.26.1`

I didn't try this, but others said it has worked.